# ggplot to create correlation graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create linear correlation graph between to variables using `ggplot2`:

```
dput(sum)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(15218, 15248, 15279, 15309, 
15340, 15371, 15400, 15431, 15461, 15492, 15522, 15553), class = "Date"), 
    Teams = c(87, 142, 173, 85, 76, 76, 93, 49, 169, 139, 60, 
    120), Scores = c("67101651", "62214988", "63183320", "66750198", 
    "61483322", "67546775", "75290893", "60713372", "77879142", 
    "70290302", "83201853", "83837301")), .Names = c("Date", 
"Teams", "Scores"), row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = "data.frame")
```

this is my command:

```
ggplot(sum, aes(x = Scores, y = Teams, group=1)) + 
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=TRUE, size=2, formula = lm(Teams ~ Scores))
```

I get this error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Teams' not found
```

any ideas?

Comment: For any future reader of this thread - to call a data frame like one of the most used base R functions is *not a good idea*. On this occasion, may I remind that `df` is also a base R function (although less often used than `sum`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a regression line on a ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633714/adding-a-regression-line-on-a-ggplot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to specify the formula for, e.g., linear model, use `y ~ poly(x, 1)`. You don't need to change the `formula` parameter as long as you want a simple linear regression (it's the default for `method = "lm"`):

```
ggplot(sum, aes(x = Scores, y = Teams, group = 1)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 1), se = TRUE, size = 2)
```

I also would recommend using `Scores` as numeric values (`as.numeric(Scores)`) if you don't want this variable to be categorial. This would change the regression line.

`Score` as categorial variable:

[image: categorial]

`Score` as numeric variable:

[image: numeric]

Comment: is there an easy way to print the r square value as a legend?

Comment: An easy way would be to print it in the the title. Just add `opts(title = bquote(R^2 ~ ":" ~ .(summary(lm(Teams ~ as.numeric(Scores), sum))$r.squared)))` to the plot.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option using `stat_cor` from the `ggpubr` package. This code will plot your points and display the correlation and p value. You can change "pearson" to "spearman" if you have non-normal data.

```
ggplot(sum, aes(x = Scores, y = Teams, group = 1)) +
  geom_point(aes()) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = TRUE, size = 2) +
  stat_cor(method = "pearson", cor.coef.name = "r", vjust = 1, size = 4)
```