# Adding a regression line on a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, linear-regression

I'm trying hard to add a regression line on a ggplot. I first tried with abline but I didn't manage to make it work. Then I tried this...

```
data = data.frame(x.plot=rep(seq(1,5),10),y.plot=rnorm(50))
ggplot(data,aes(x.plot,y.plot))+stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_normal) +
   geom_smooth(method='lm',formula=data$y.plot~data$x.plot)
```

But it is not working either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add regression line equation and R^2 on graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549694/add-regression-line-equation-and-r2-on-graph)

Answer (score 262, accepted):

In general, to provide your own formula you should use arguments `x` and `y` that will correspond to values you provided in `ggplot()` - in this case `x` will be interpreted as `x.plot` and `y` as `y.plot`. You can find more information about smoothing methods and formula via the help page of function `stat_smooth()` as it is the default stat used by `geom_smooth()`.

```
ggplot(data,aes(x.plot, y.plot)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_normal) + 
  geom_smooth(method='lm', formula= y~x)
```

If you are using the same x and y values that you supplied in the `ggplot()` call and need to plot the linear regression line then you don't need to use the formula inside `geom_smooth()`, just supply the `method="lm"`.

```
ggplot(data,aes(x.plot, y.plot)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data= mean_cl_normal) + 
  geom_smooth(method='lm')
```

Comment: @ Didzis Elferts is there any way to show the slope of regression line while using the geom_smooth? thanks

Answer (score 74):

As I just figured, in case you have a **model fitted on multiple linear regression**, the above mentioned solution won't work.

You have to create your line manually as a dataframe that contains predicted values for your original dataframe (in your case `data`).

It would look like this:

```
# read dataset
df = mtcars

# create multiple linear model
lm_fit <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + hp, data=df)
summary(lm_fit)

# save predictions of the model in the new data frame 
# together with variable you want to plot against
predicted_df <- data.frame(mpg_pred = predict(lm_fit, df), hp=df$hp)

# this is the predicted line of multiple linear regression
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) + 
  geom_point(color='blue') +
  geom_line(color='red',data = predicted_df, aes(x=mpg_pred, y=hp))
```

[image: Multiple LR]

```
# this is predicted line comparing only chosen variables
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) + 
  geom_point(color='blue') +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)
```

[image: Single LR]

Comment: One thing to watch out for is the convention is lm(y~x). I got a little turned around for a second reading this since the variable you're 'predicting' is on the x-axis. Great answer though.

Answer (score 50):

The simple and versatile solution is to draw a line using `slope` and `intercept` from [`geom_abline`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_abline.html). Example usage with a scatterplot and `lm` object:

```
library(tidyverse)
petal.lm <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, iris)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Petal.Length)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_abline(slope = coef(petal.lm)[["Petal.Width"]], 
              intercept = coef(petal.lm)[["(Intercept)"]])
```

[image: Example plot]

`coef` is used to extract the coefficients of the formula provided to `lm`. If you have some other linear model object or line to plot, just plug in the slope and intercept values similarly.

Comment: And so you never worry about ordering of your formulas or just adding a `+0` you can use names. `data.lm$coefficients[['(Intercept)']]` and `data.lm$coefficients[['DepDelay']]`.

Comment: (Almost) always `(Intercept)` will be listed first. The names do make the code clearer.

Comment: I think this is the best answer - it is the most versatile.

Comment: How do I make use of this (plot it)?

Comment: @Ben sorry for late response. Since this answer is getting some attention, I've added details for a MWE.

Comment: I've searched through the internet, and this is by far the best solution that I've found so far. I think that adding the precise name of the covariate after the coef - like Ufos mentioned above - is the safest approach. Like this: ```coef(your_model_name_here)[['your_covariate_name_here']]``` Thus you won't accidentally plot the regression curve of a (confounding) covariate that is not of interest in the graph.

Comment: @jaggedjava after thinking about it, I do see the reduced confusion being a benefit compared to the brevity of numeric indices, so I have modified the code

Answer (score 6):

I found this function on a [blog](https://sejohnston.com/2012/08/09/a-quick-and-easy-function-to-plot-lm-results-in-r/)

```
 ggplotRegression <- function (fit) {

    `require(ggplot2)

    ggplot(fit$model, aes_string(x = names(fit$model)[2], y = names(fit$model)[1])) + 
      geom_point() +
      stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "red") +
      labs(title = paste("Adj R2 = ",signif(summary(fit)$adj.r.squared, 5),
                         "Intercept =",signif(fit$coef[[1]],5 ),
                         " Slope =",signif(fit$coef[[2]], 5),
                         " P =",signif(summary(fit)$coef[2,4], 5)))
    }`
```

once you loaded the function you could simply

```
ggplotRegression(fit)
```

you can also go for `ggplotregression( y ~ x + z + Q, data)`

Hope this helps.

Comment: An explanation of this code would greatly improve this answer. The labels are unnecessary and you should be using `coef(fit)` instead of accessing coefficients directly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824461/is-there-a-reason-to-prefer-extractor-functions-to-accessing-attributes-with

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fit other type of models, like a dose-response curve using logistic models you would also need to create more data points with the function predict if you want to have a smoother regression line:

fit: your fit of a logistic regression curve

```
#Create a range of doses:
mm <- data.frame(DOSE = seq(0, max(data$DOSE), length.out = 100))
#Create a new data frame for ggplot using predict and your range of new 
#doses:
fit.ggplot=data.frame(y=predict(fit, newdata=mm),x=mm$DOSE)

ggplot(data=data,aes(x=log10(DOSE),y=log(viability)))+geom_point()+
geom_line(data=fit.ggplot,aes(x=log10(x),y=log(y)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to use geom_line() to add regression line is to use broom package to get fitted values and use it as shown here
https://cmdlinetips.com/2022/06/add-regression-line-to-scatterplot-ggplot2/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).