# Adding multiple regression line in scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

My graph looks like this:

[image]

As you can see there are 4 parameters (Treatment): `NC`, `NF`, `TC`, and `TF`.
X axis shows the species number and Y shows the weight of crops.
I want to draw a regression line of each with relation to species number? 
I tried `abline` but no luck.

Thanks

My code

```
ggplot(wheatX,aes(x=No.of.species,y=Weight,label=Treatment))+geom_point()+geom_text(aes(label=Treatment),hjust=0, vjust=0)
```

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633714/adding-a-regression-line-on-a-ggplot

Comment: @Chris Thanks. It wasnt accurate. But I found the geom_smooth. I researched it a bit and found the appropriate method that can be applied in my case. Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow (SO)! It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you make a minimal reproducible example to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to solve your problem. You can have a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to make a great reproducible example in R.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments suggest, you should provide a minimal reproducible example.

Creating a dummy data set with two types

```
dd = data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5 + rnorm(10), type=c("A", "B"))
```

We first fit a regression model

```
m = lm(y ~ x + type, data=dd)
```

Then use the predict function

dd_m = data.frame(x=dd$x, y=predict(m, dd), type=dd$type)

to predict from the model using our original data set. This now gives a data frame `dd_m` that we can put in a standard `geom_line` call

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dd) + geom_point(aes(x, y, colour=type)) + 
  geom_line(data=dd_m, aes(x, y, colour=type))
```

To get

[image]