# Multiple least squares quadratic fit in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, quadratic-curve

> Notice that your graphic constructed from Problem 4 shows a quadratic
>   or curved relationship between **log_wages** against **exp**. The next
>   task is to plot three quadratic functions for each race level "black",
>   "white" and "other".  To estimate the quadratic fit, you can use the
>   following function **quad_fit**:

````
```{r}
quad_fit <- function(data_sub) {
  return(lm(log_wage~exp+I(exp^2),data=data_sub)$coefficients)
}
quad_fit(salary_data)
```
````

> The above function computes the least squares quadratic fit and
>   returns coefficients a1, a2, a3, where
>
> Y(hat) = a1 + a2x + a3x^2
>
> where Y(hat) = log(wage) and x = exp
>
> Use **ggplot** to accomplish this task or use base R graphics for
>   partial credit.  Make sure to include a legend and appropriate labels.

**My attempt**

```
blackfit <- quad_fit(salary_data[salary_data$race == "black",])
whitefit <- quad_fit(salary_data[salary_data$race == "white",])
otherfit <- quad_fit(salary_data[salary_data$race == "other",])

yblack <- blackfit[1] + blackfit[2]*salary_data$exp + blackfit[3]*(salary_data$exp)^2
ywhite <- whitefit[1] + whitefit[2]*salary_data$exp + whitefit[3]*(salary_data$exp)^2
yother <- otherfit[1] + otherfit[2]*salary_data$exp + otherfit[3]*(salary_data$exp)^2

soloblack <- salary_data[salary_data$race == "black",]
solowhite <- salary_data[salary_data$race == "white",]
soloother <- salary_data[salary_data$race == "other",]

ggplot(data = soloblack) +
  geom_point(aes(x = exp, y = log_wage)) +
  stat_smooth(aes(y = log_wage, x = exp), formula = y ~ yblack)
```

This is only the first attempt for the data filtered with for race == "black".
I am not clear how the formula should look like because through the quad_fit function it seems it already does the calculations for you.

Comment: Where is *your graphic constructed from Problem 4*? Simply pass in subsets to that process.

Comment: library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = salary_data) +
  geom_point(aes(x = exp, y = log_wage, alpha = exp)) +
  labs(x = "Job Experience", y = "Log of Wage", title = "Salary Dataset")

This is the code for the graph, but I feel my arguments in geom_smooth are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Consider plotting fitted values using output of `quad_fit` (as shown by [@StefanK here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46217047/1422451)) and use `by` to plot across all distinct values of *race*:

```
reg_plot <- function(sub) {
   # PREDICTED DATA FOR LINE PLOT
   q_fit <- quad_fit(sub)
   predicted_df <- data.frame(wage_pred = predict(q_fit, sub), exp = sub$exp)

   # ORIGINAL SCATTER PLOT WITH PREDICTED LINE
   ggplot(data = sub) + 
     geom_point(aes(x = exp, y = log_wage, alpha = exp)) +
     labs(x = "Job Experience", y = "Log of Wage", 
          title = paste("Wage and Job Experience Plot for",    
                        sub$race[[1]], "in Salary Dataset") 
     geom_line(color='red', data = predicted_df, aes(x = exp, y = wage_pred))
}

# RUN GRAPHS FOR EACH RACE
by(salary_data, salary_data$race, reg_plot)
```