# Is there a R function to add Regression Line and Regression equation to ggplot

Tags: r

I have used ggplot to the below dataframe(cars dataset) for 2 categories. I need to have 2 regression equations for 2 categories. Below is the code I have executed to plot the graph

```
 cars$cat <- ifelse(cars$speed>10,"greater than 10","less than 10")
ggplot(cars,aes(x=dist,y=speed,color=cat))+geom_point()+geom_smooth(method = lm)
```

Can you help me in putting the 2 regression equations

Comment: Your codes are already generating two lines on the graph. I don't understand the point.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to add regression equations not regression lines. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/35140066/3184024

Comment: @ Maydin, I need to add regression equation near the plot.

Comment: @wici, thanks. I did see that, Is there not a easier way than that?

Comment: @RferR So please change the title of the question, because it is *"Is there a R function to add Regression **line** to ggplot"*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a regression line on a ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633714/adding-a-regression-line-on-a-ggplot)

Comment: @Grada, thanks, But I need to add regression equation as well