# R function to create single regression line for subset of dataset

Tags: r

Using instructions and data from this link:
[https://people.math.carleton.ca/~davecampbell/datasets/2020/07/24/trade-data-monthly-exports-of-grains-open-canada/](https://people.math.carleton.ca/%7Edavecampbell/datasets/2020/07/24/trade-data-monthly-exports-of-grains-open-canada/)

"First subset the data so that you are only considering   two commodities: “Barley”, “Oats”.
Make sure you color the points with the type of commodity. Include in your plot one single regression line for this subset of the dataset, add a second regression line for this subset of data, but make sure you force the line to have a zero intercept."

Currently my code looks like this but error of unknown column 'total' is coming up. Not sure how to plot a regression line with a subset within data:

```
export_data |> group_by(year, Commodity, Destinations) |> 
filter(Commodity == "Barley" | Commodity == "Oats") |> 
summarize(total = sum(VALUE)) |>
subset(Destinations == "Total exports, all destinations") |>
ungroup() |> 
ggplot( aes(x = year, y = total, group = Commodity)) +
labs(y = "total export (tonnes)") +
geom_point(aes(color = Commodity)) +
ggtitle("Total Barley and Oats export to all destinations")
x <- export_data$year
y <- export_data$total
abline(lm(y ~ x, data = export_data), col = "yellow")
```

Comment: Maybe look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633714/adding-a-regression-line-on-a-ggplot).

Answer (score 0):

you first need to swtich x and y. It is y against x.